# Scaling radar plot for large value in R(with the data)

Tags: r, plot, visualization, radar-chart

I have a data set for which I want to create a radar plot

```
str(trial4)
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  6 variables:
$ Var1    : Factor w/ 4 levels "2009-04-01","2010-04-01",..: 1 2 3 4
$ Arsenic : int  66 8 8 5
$ Fluoride: int  11775 10788 10724 7130
$ Iron    : int  103 60 54 46
$ Nitrate : int  927 856 1106 624
$ Salinity: int  24787 23168 20258 18924
```

My radar plot code executes fine and I get the plot like this

```
radarchart(trial4,seg=6)
colors_border=c( rgb(0.2,0.5,0.5,0.9), rgb(0.8,0.2,0.5,0.9) ,  rgb(0.7,0.5,0.1,0.9) )
colors_in=c( rgb(0.2,0.5,0.5,0.4), rgb(0.8,0.2,0.5,0.4) ,  rgb(0.7,0.5,0.1,0.4) )
radarchart( trial4  , axistype=1 , 
        #custom polygon
        pcol=colors_border , pfcol=colors_in , plwd=2 , plty=1,
        #custom the grid
        cglcol="grey", cglty=1, axislabcol="grey", caxislabels=seq(0,20,5), cglwd=0.8,
        #custom labels
        vlcex=0.8
        )
        legend(x=0.7, y=1, legend = rownames(trial4[-c(1,2),]), bty = "n", pch=20 , col=colors_in , text.col = "grey", cex=1.2, pt.cex=3)
```

[image: radar plot 1]

As one can see, the problem is the scaling I cannot fit in the plot. I searched online, but it's not clear how I can make the polygon fit inside the grid of the radar plot. I tried adding xlim and ylim:

```
radarchart(trial4,seg=6)
colors_border=c( rgb(0.2,0.5,0.5,0.9), rgb(0.8,0.2,0.5,0.9) , rgb(0.7,0.5,0.1,0.9) )
colors_in=c( rgb(0.2,0.5,0.5,0.4), rgb(0.8,0.2,0.5,0.4) , rgb(0.7,0.5,0.1,0.4) )
radarchart( trial4  , axistype=1 , 
        #custom polygon
        pcol=colors_border , pfcol=colors_in , plwd=2 , plty=1,
        #custom the grid
        cglcol="grey", cglty=1, axislabcol="grey", caxislabels=seq(0,20,5), cglwd=0.8,
        #custom labels
        vlcex=0.8,xlim=c(0,2),ylim=c(0,10)
        ) 
        legend(x=0.7, y=1, legend = rownames(trial4[-c(1,2),]), bty = "n", pch=20  ,  col=colors_in , text.col = "grey", cex=1.2, pt.cex=3)
```

[image: radar plot 2]

but still I am not able to scale this properly.

**Is there any parameter I am missing?**.

so here is my data , and the package i am using is `fmsb`

```
var1<-c("2009-04-01","2010-04-01","2011-04-01","2012-04-01")
Arsenic<-c(66,8,8,5)
Fluoride<-c(11775,10788,10724,7130)
Iron<-c(103,60,54,46)
Nitrate<-c(927,856,1106,624)
Salinity<-c(24787,23168,20258,18924)
```

`trail4<-as.data.frame(var1,Arsenic,Fluoride,Iron,Nitrate,Salinity)`

Comment: Please post a reproducible problem (with some made up data), and also you will have to mention which package contains the `radarplot` function.

Comment: i have edited the question.